# What does mean by the sentence "an $R$-module $M$ is $x$-torsion free"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> What does mean by the sentence "**an $R$-module $M$ is $x$-torsion free**", for $x \in R$ a fixed element?

I got some information as follows:

If $M$ is $x$-torsion free if for each $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have a short exact sequence like
$$ 0 \to M/x^n M \xrightarrow{x^m} M/x^{m+n}M \xrightarrow{?} M/x^mM \to 0.$$

Is it true?

If this is true, what is 2nd map (?) above?

How to  prove it?

Comment: My guess is that $x$ is considered to be a fixed element of $R$, and $M$ is $x$-torsion free means that multiplication by $x$ is an injective morphism $M \to M$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler, in that case what would be the next map? Is it also multiplication map?

Comment: The second map would just be $m + x^{m+n} M \mapsto m + x^m M$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler, you mean multiplication by $x^{-n}$

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR That may not even make sense! But $x^{m+n}M\subseteq x^mM$, which means there is a canonical map from $M/x^{m+n}M$ to $M/x^mM$, given by Daniel Schepler. But that does not mean "multiply by $x^{-n}$, because that need not make sense at all.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, ok, thanks. So what is the exact definition of $x$-torsion freeness of a module for fixed $x$ ?